# Rename Dataframe Column Names in R using Previous Column Name and Regex Pattern

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am working in R for the first time and I have been having difficulty renaming column names in a dataframe (Grade.Data). I have a dataset imported from an csv file that has column names like this:
    Student.ID

```
Grade    

Interactive.Exercises.1..Health

Interactive.Exercises.2..Fitness

Quizzes.1..Week.1.Quiz

Quizzes.2..Week.2.Quiz

Case.Studies.1..Case.Study1

Case.Studies.2..Case.Study2
```

I would like to be able to change the variable names so that they are more simple, i.e. from Interactive.Exercises.1.Health to Interactive.Exercises.1 or Quizzes.1.Week.1.Quiz to Quizzes.1

So far, I have tried this:

```
grep(".*[0-9]", names(Grade.Data))
```

But I get this returned:

```
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on, and write a better regex expression? Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you want `names(Grade.Data) <- sub("^(.*[^.])\\..*$", "\\1", names(Grade.Data))`. What about `Case.Studies.2..Case.Study2`, what is the expected output? Also, try `"^(.*[^.])\\.{2}.*"` pattern.

Comment: I would like to have Case.Studies.2..Case.Study2 change to Case.Studies2, from the first half of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you truncate column names after the first chunk of digits.

You may use the following `sub` solution:

```
names(Grade.Data) <- sub("^(.*?\\d+).*$", "\\1", names(Grade.Data))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJLxqs/2/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?\\d+)` - Group 1 (later referred with `\1` from the replacement pattern) matching any 0+ chars as few as possible (`.*?`) and then 1 or more digits (`\d+`)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Thank you everyone for your help as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your regex itself. What you are looking for is probably the combination of `regexpr` - which gets the start and ending of your regex- and `regmatches` - which gets the actual string corresponding to the output of `regexpr`:

```
start_end <- regexpr(".*[0-9]", names(Grade.data))
regmatches(names(Grade.data), start_end)
# [1] "Interactive.Exercises.1"     "Interactive.Exercises.2"    
# [3] "Quizzes.1..Week.1"           "Quizzes.2..Week.2"          
# [5] "Case.Studies.1..Case.Study1"
```

Adding a question-mark behind the dot-star will make the regex match as few characters as possible, so it will stop after the first numeric value:

```
start_end <- regexpr(".*?[0-9]", names(Grade.data))
regmatches(names(Grade.data), start_end)
# [1] "Interactive.Exercises.1"     "Interactive.Exercises.2"    
# [3] "Quizzes.1"      "Quizzes.2"          
# [5] "Case.Studies.1"
```

Comment: This works, but how would I change the actual names of the columns? I tried names(Grade.Data) <-start_end but it changed the column names to -1 1 1 1 1 -1 and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the function `names`, following I write a little example, the names string can be as long as you need.

```
names(x = Grade.Data) <- c("Col1_name", "Col2_name")
```

Comment: Except, I have so many variables, I don't want to rename each one individually. I was hoping to find something that would work with what I have already and just keep the selection I wanted.