# Systematically rename column names using pre-existing name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, col

I have a data frame formatted like so:

```
val1 = c(.35, .36, .35, .22, .27, .25)
val2 = c(.35, .35, .37, .40, .42, .46)
val3 = c(.88, .9, .87, .35, .35, .36)
val4 = c(.9, .91, .82, .36, .36, .36)
df = data.frame (val1, val2, val3, val4)
colnames(df)[1] = "group 1_31"
colnames(df)[2] = "group 1_32"
colnames(df)[3] = "group 2_32"
colnames(df)[4] = "group 10_310"
```

I know these column names are less than ideal, but unfortunately they are automatically supplied by the program I'm running. I'd like to rename each column, such that group a_bc becomes bca, like so:

```
colnames(df)[1] = "311"
colnames(df)[2] = "321"
colnames(df)[3] = "322"
colnames(df)[4] = "31010"
```

I know I can get rid of "group" by doing:

```
colnames(df)=sub("group ","",colnames(df))
```

but that still leaves me with "1_31", "1_32", etc.

Is there a way to automatically convert a_bc to bca across all columns names (I have 55 that need this conversion)?

I've read [Rename Dataframe Column Names in R using Previous Column Name and Regex Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680290/rename-dataframe-column-names-in-r-using-previous-column-name-and-regex-pattern) but I think my case is different because I need to reorder the existing column name, not just cut them off at a specific position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can rearrange the backreferences after capturing as a group

```
colnames(df) <- sub('group (\\d+)_(\\d+)', "\\2\\1", colnames(df))
colnames(df)
#[1] "311"   "321"   "322"   "31010"
```

Comment: Can you briefly exlpain what is this doing? It seems to me: you define group with first element(\\d+) and a second element after the _ (\\d). Then in the replacement of the sub funtion basically you are saying to switch the positions. What if i put colnames(df3) = sub('group (\\d+)_(\\d+)', "\\3\\1", colnames(df3))? I obtain c(1,1,2,10). Why? Thank you

Comment: @Carlo the pattern match.ed is after the `group` and space (` `), capture one or more. digits inside brackets (`(\\d+)`) followed by `_`, then then second set of digits in capture grouop.  In the replacement, we. switch the backreference in the reverse order i.e. 2nd followed by 1st (`\\2\\1`)

Answer (score 2):

```
val1 = c(.35, .36, .35, .22, .27, .25)
val2 = c(.35, .35, .37, .40, .42, .46)
val3 = c(.88, .9, .87, .35, .35, .36)
val4 = c(.9, .91, .82, .36, .36, .36)
df = data.frame (val1, val2, val3, val4)
colnames(df)[1] = "group 1_31"
colnames(df)[2] = "group 1_32"
colnames(df)[3] = "group 2_32"
colnames(df)[4] = "group 10_310"

gsub("^group (\\d+)_(\\d+)", "\\2\\1", colnames(df))
[1] "311"   "321"   "322"   "31010"
```